# Unwrap mp4 from flv video

Tags: php, ffmpeg, containers, flv, mp4

I used ffmpeg to wrap an mp4 (h264) file in an flv container.  I need to do this to inject metadata into the flv for pseudostreaming to Flash players.

My question, once the wrapped flv file is on my server, is there a way to output the mp4 file to a browser using PHP?  That way I can just have the one flv file, but send it as an mp4 to mobile devices and as an flv to Flash capable devices?

From what I understand the mp4 was not re-encoded, but just given a flv header.  I am hoping there is a way to get the mp4 data and spit it out on the fly.

Comment: Are you low on disk space? Wouldn't it be easier to keep both files on the server?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Juhana.  I'm currently keeping both files on the server and I have 300GB of space, so I'm not even close to running out.  But the videos are about 500mb each (1.5 hours long), so I thought it might be better to just have one file. Is it impractical to do it that way?

Comment: I don't think that you will be able to do this in pure PHP. Don't you have the possibility to execute ffmpeg from your PHP script for extracting the video? I also thought, that flash should be able to stream mp4/h264?